# Ecto join with dynamically built conditions

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm trying to build an Ecto query with a left join with optional extra conditions on the join. I'll try to describe it with the typical posts and comments example.

Post has_many Comments
Comment belongs_to Post.

Let's say Comment has two boolean fields, approved and featured.

I want to get all Posts regardless of whether they have comments or not, hence the left join.
I want comments preloaded but preferably one SQL query.
I want to optionally filter comments on approved and featured.

I'm trying to write a function something like this where if approved or featured is not nil, they will be included in the join, if they are nil, they will be ignored.  I haven't found a better way than something like this:

```
def posts_with_comments(approved, featured, some_var) do
  query = Post
  |> where([p], p.some_field == ^some_var

  cond do
    !is_nil(approved) and !is_nil(featured)
      -> join(query, :left, [p], c in Comment, [post_id: p.id, approved: ^approved, featured: ^featured])

    !is_nil(approved)
      -> join(query, :left, [p], c in Comment, [post_id: p.id, approved: ^approved])

    !is_nil(featured)
      -> join(query, :left, [p], c in Comment, [post_id: p.id, featured: ^featured])

    true -> join(query, :left, [p], c in Comment, [post_id: p.id])
  end

  |> preload([p, c], [comments: c])
  |> select([p], p)
  |> Repo.all

end
```

That works but there must be a better way. It would get crazy if I had a third parameter.  I'm looking for a way to dynamically build that list for the `on` parameter of `join()`. My attempts to do that have failed because of the requirement to pin.

I can't put those conditions in a `where` because if I do something like `where t.approved == true` I get only posts approved comments.

Comment: why not use guards? such as 
`def posts_with_comments(approved, featured, some_var) do` and `def posts_with_comments(approved, featured, some_var) when is_nil?(approved) do` and so on

Comment: @Felipe-Skinner If I'm understanding you correctly, that might work but I'm trying to avoid the explosion of condition testing whether in guards or whereever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is to use the [dynamic](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#dynamic/2) function.

This works. (leaving out the some_var condition I had earlier).

```
def posts_with_comments(approved, featured) do
  query = Post
  join(query, :left, [p], c in Comment, ^do_join(approved, featured))
  |> preload([p, c], [comments: c])
  |> Repo.all
end

defp do_join(approved, featured) do
  dynamic = dynamic([p, c], c.post_id == p.id)

  dynamic =
  case approved do
    nil -> dynamic
    _ -> dynamic([p, c], ^dynamic and c.approved == ^approved)
  end

  case featured do
    nil -> dynamic
    _ -> dynamic([p, c], ^dynamic and c.featured == ^featured)
  end
end
```

That's much better than my first attempt because it's a simple concatenation that just gets longer with more conditions rather than an explosion of conditions.

As an exercise I have been unable to make this more generic by feeding it a list of fields and using something like reduce. The problem I had there was making the field name (e.g., c.approved) work from a variable.

`join` seems to support two types of `on` parameters. The keyword list (which I assume implies ==) and the more expressive format.  `dynamic` does not seem to work with the keyword list. It tries to expand p.id to p.id().

I couldn't get @mudasobwa's macro based solutions to work. I'm not exactly a macro expert yet but I don't see how the nil match can work at run time.

One more thing about the macro solution. For some reason, it doesn't work with the keyword list either. I would expect a bare bones macro like this to work:

```
defmacrop do_join do
  quote do
    [post_id: p.id]
  end
end
```

But it doesn't. It tries to expand p.id to p.id()

Answer (score 1):

I would go with declaring a helper and pattern match arguments in it:

```rb
def posts_with_comments(approved, featured, some_var) do
  query = Post
          |> where([p], p.some_field == ^some_var)
          |> join(:left, [p], c in Comment, do_join(approved, featured))
          |> preload([p, c], [comments: c])
          |> select([p], p)
          |> Repo.all
end

defmacrop do_join(nil, nil) do
  quote do: [post_id: p.id]
end
defmacrop do_join(approved, nil) do
  quote bind_quoted: [approved: approved] do
    [post_id: p.id, approved: ^approved]
  end
end
defmacrop do_join(nil, featured) do
  quote bind_quoted: [featured: featured] do
    [post_id: p.id, featured: ^featured]
  end
end
defmacrop do_join(approved, featured) do
  quote bind_quoted: [approved: approved, featured: featured] do
    [post_id: p.id, approved: ^approved, featured: ^featured]
  end
end
```

`defmacro` is necessary to allow pin operators out of context.

Or, alternatively, `Enum.reduce/3` it:

```rb
# kw is approved: approved, featured: featured
defmacrop do_join(kw) do
  initial = [{:post_id, {{:., [], [{:p, [], Elixir}, :id]}, [], []}}]
  Enum.reduce(kw, initial, fn
    {_, nil}, acc -> acc
    {k, _}, acc ->
      quoted = {k, {:^, [], [{k, [], Elixir}]}}
      [quoted | acc]
  end)
end
```

Comment: would guards work as well or macro is just a better approach to this?

Comment: Thanks @mudasobwa although I haven't had much luck yet. I've only tried the second option with the reduce.  I think there's a `end)` missing before the other ends and it should be `defmacro`, not `defmacrop`. After that it still won't compile when I try to use do_join(approved: approved). `do_join(approved: approved) is not a valid query expression`. I also tried a very simple macro which always simply returns [post_id: p.id]

Comment: Sorry, I thought macrop was a typo but I now realize it means private macro and it needs to be in the file before using. But ... it still doesn't work. `(Ecto.Query.CompileError) Enum.reduce( ... is not a valid query expression`. I don't really need this so it's more of a learning exercise now but it would be useful to get the reduce version working for future use.

Comment: Indeed, `defmacrop` should return the AST that is acceptable by `query` macro, that’s why `Enum.reduce` should not appear there. Instead, `Enum.reduce` should be accomplished on _compilation stage_. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @mudasobwa, That still does not compile. I think there's a `)` missing from the first `end` but after fixing that, it says `syntax error before: post_id`. It doesn't seem to like the post_id: atom.   I appreciate your efforts but it's probably not worth spending more time on. I'm pretty happy with the solution using `dynamic`.

Comment: Indeed, I have it fixed _and checked_. Now it should work.

Comment: Sorry, it still doesn't work for me. I'm not sure why but I've pasted your macro code exactly and calling it in the join with `do_join(approved: approved, featured: featured)` but it gives `{:featured, ^featured} is not a valid query expression` on the line number with the join.

Comment: OK, this is an `Ecto` glitch and honestly, I ran out of ideas on how to make it Ecto-friendly. In Elixir `[{:key, :value}]` and `[key: :value]` are 100% identical, Ecto somehow treats it differently. If you could provide MCVE I could try to make it work.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your help. It's an interesting challenge. If I find the time I'll put up a MCVE but it really is as I describe. A simple Post with a one to many relationship to Comment which has the two booleans. Nothing at all unusual. For now, the `dynamic` approach works fine. If I had found that first, I probably wouldn't have posted the question.